# Combining F# async functions

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I'm a bit frustrated here. I know I've got all the bits, but I can't work out how to combine them...

```
let saveImageToDisk path content =
    async {
        use s = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        do! s.AsyncWrite(content)
        printfn "Done writing %A" path
        } // returns Async<unit>

let getImages imageUrls =
    imageUrls
        |> Seq.map (fun url -> topath url, getImage url)
        //Next line not happy because content is Async<byte[]> instead of byte[]
        |> Seq.map (fun (path, content) -> saveImageToDisk path content)
        |> Async.Parallel
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine the two using the `async` expression:

```
let getImages imageUrls =
    imageUrls
        |> Seq.map (fun url -> async {
              let! content = getImage url
              return! saveImageToDisk (topath url) content })
        |> Async.Parallel
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: Basically, since Async is a monad, you combine both of them in another Async. :)