# How to handle HttpWebRequest timeout in F# Async.Parallel

Tags: asynchronous, f#, httpwebrequest

I just spent a long time breaking my teeth on why this code was 'hanging' for some urls:

```
let getImage (imageUrl:string) =
    async {
        try
            let req = WebRequest.Create(imageUrl) :?> HttpWebRequest
            req.UserAgent <- "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)";
            req.Method <- "GET";
            req.AllowAutoRedirect <- true;
            req.MaximumAutomaticRedirections <- 4;
            req.Timeout <- 3000; //HAHAHA, nice try!
            let! response1 = req.AsyncGetResponse()
            let response = response1 :?> HttpWebResponse
            use stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            let ms = new MemoryStream()
            let bytesRead = ref 1
            let buffer = Array.create 0x1000 0uy
            while !bytesRead > 0 do
                bytesRead := stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, !bytesRead)
            return SuccessfulDownload(imageUrl, ms.ToArray())

        with
            ex -> return FailedDownload(imageUrl, ex.Message)
    }
```

After managing to track down which of the 3000 urls was hanging, I learned that `AsyncGetResponse` doesn't take any notice of `HttpWebRequest.Timeout`. I've done a bit of searching which throws up suggestions of wrapping the async request in a thread with a timer. That's great for C#, but if I'm running 3000 of these through `Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously`, what's the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: You should just do [`stream.CopyTo ms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) rather than all the manual copying with `buffer` and `bytesRead`.

Comment: @ildjarn, thanks for the info, I have to admit it was a straight copy-paste from [here](http://fdatamining.blogspot.com/2010/07/f-async-workflow-application-flickr.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've only roughly tested this, but it should have the correct behavior:

```
type System.Net.WebRequest with
  member req.AsyncGetResponseWithTimeout () =
    let impl = async {
      let iar = req.BeginGetResponse (null, null)
      let! success = Async.AwaitIAsyncResult (iar, req.Timeout)
      return if success then req.EndGetResponse iar
             else req.Abort ()
                  raise (System.Net.WebException "The operation has timed out") }
    Async.TryCancelled (impl, fun _ -> req.Abort ())
```

In your code, call `req.AsyncGetResponseWithTimeout()` instead of `req.AsyncGetResponse()`.

Comment: Hm, I spoke too soon. It works well for a few, but I'm getting a heck of a lot of timeouts now. Is it possible that WebRequest manages the number of concurrent connections internally, and now I'm timing out on queued requests? I'll keep digging...

Comment: @Benjol : Yep, as I recall, by default it's internally limited to two simultaneous connections. I seem to remember that being pretty trivial to work around though. I'll look through some old C# code of mine to try and remember how.

Comment: @Benjol : It appears that setting [System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) and/or [System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.connectionlimit.aspx) is the key.

Comment: Spent a while wrangling this code. My current understanding is that all of these WebRequests are launched 'immediately', so to get it to work I have to set the timeout to the time required to download *all* of them. Haven't had time to investigate further.

Comment: @Benjol : That implies a problem with how you *use* `getImage`, not a problem with `getImage` itself (or with `AsyncGetResponseWithTimeout`).

Comment: @ildjarn, good point! I'd forgotten that I hadn't included that. It's in the answer [here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693279/combining-f-async-functions)