# Timeout on WebRequest with F#-Style Asynchronous Workflows

Tags: asynchronous, f#, httpwebrequest

For a broader context, here is **[my code](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/500606/)**, which downloads a list of URLs.

It seems to me that there is no good way to handle timeouts in F# when using `use! response = request.AsyncGetResponse()` style URL fetching. I have pretty much everything working as I'd like it too (error handling and asynchronous request and response downloading) save the problem that occurs when a website takes a long time to response. My current code just hangs indefinitely. I've tried it on a PHP script I wrote that waits 300 seconds. It waited the whole time.

I have found "solutions" of two sorts, both of which are undesirable.

### `AwaitIAsyncResult` + `BeginGetResponse`

Like the answer by **ildjarn** on [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713330/how-to-handle-httpwebrequest-timeout-in-f-async-parallel). The problem with this is that if you have queued many asynchronous requests, some are artificially blocked on `AwaitIAsyncResult`. In other words, the call to make the request has been made, but something behind the scenes is blocking the call. This causes the time-out on `AwaitIAsyncResult` to be triggered prematurely when many concurrent requests are made. My guess is  a limit on the number of requests to a single domain or just a limit on total requests.

To support my suspicion I wrote little WPF application to draw a timeline of when the requests seem to be starting and ending. In my code linked above, notice the timer start and stops on lines 49 and 54 (calling line 10). Here is the [resulting timeline image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12zvI.jpg).

When I move the timer start to after the initial response (so I am only timing the downloading of the contents), [the timeline looks a lot more realistic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E5Uf.jpg). Note, these are two separate runs, but no code change aside from where the timer is started. Instead of having the `startTime` measured directly before `use! response = request.AsyncGetResponse()`, I have it directly afterwards.

To further support my claim, I made a timeline with [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). Here is [the resulting timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpCK7.png). **Clearly the requests aren't starting exactly when I tell them to.**

### `GetResponseStream` in a new thread

In other words, synchronous requests and download calls are made in a secondary thread. This *does* work, since `GetResponseStream` respects the `Timeout` property on the `WebRequest` object. But in the process, we lose all of the waiting time as the request is on the wire and the response hasn't come back yet. We might as well write it in C#... ;)

### Questions

- Is this a known problem?
- Is there any good solution that takes advantage of F# asynchronous workflows and still allows timeouts *and* error handling?
- If the problem is really that I am making too many requests at once, then would the best way to limit the number of request be to use a `Semaphore(5, 5)` or something like that?
- *Side Question:* if you've looked at my code, can you see any stupid things I've done and could fix?

If there is anything you are confused about, please let me know.

Comment: Read the comments on my answer that you linked to -- I gave links to documentation describing how to overrule the default two-connection-limit.

Comment: @ildjarn I saw the links before but I continue to pursue this issue because I think there is a deeper problem that changing the connection limit does not address, i.e. how can a developer know if that invisible idle time between issuing the call to start the request and the request actually starting is occurring or if the request is just very slow.

Comment: Presumably that invisible idle time would be non-existent if the connection limit were removed, so that seems to be begging the question.

Comment: @JoelVerhagen, did you see the answers on my follow-on question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219726/throttled-async-download-in-f)? I managed to get something sort-of working, but didn't go into the detailed analysis that you have here. I'd be interested in feedback if you do try 'my' solution...

Answer (score 0):

AsyncGetResponse simply ignoring any timeout value posted... here's a solution we just cooked:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Net

type Request = Request of WebRequest * AsyncReplyChannel<WebResponse>

let requestAgent =
    MailboxProcessor.Start <| fun inbox -> async {
            while true do
                let! (Request (req, port)) = inbox.Receive ()

                async {
                    try
                        let! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse ()
                        port.Reply resp
                    with
                    | ex -> sprintf "Exception in child %s\n%s" (ex.GetType().Name) ex.Message |> Console.WriteLine
                } |> Async.Start
        }

let getHTML url =
    async {
        try
            let req = "http://" + url |> WebRequest.Create
            try
                use! resp = requestAgent.PostAndAsyncReply ((fun chan -> Request (req, chan)), 1000)
                use str = resp.GetResponseStream ()
                use rdr = new StreamReader (str)
                return Some <| rdr.ReadToEnd ()
            with
            | :? System.TimeoutException ->
                req.Abort()
                Console.WriteLine "RequestAgent call timed out"
                return None
        with
        | ex ->
            sprintf "Exception in request %s\n\n%s" (ex.GetType().Name) ex.Message |> Console.WriteLine
            return None
    } |> Async.RunSynchronously;;

getHTML "www.grogogle.com"
```

i.e. We're delegating to another agent and calling it providing an async timeout... if we do not get a reply from the agent in the specified amount of time we abort the request and move on.

Answer (score 0):

I see my other answer may fail to answer your particular question... here's another implementation for a task limiter that doesn't require the use of semaphore.

```
open System

type IParallelLimiter =
    abstract GetToken : unit -> Async<IDisposable>

type Message= 
    | GetToken of AsyncReplyChannel<IDisposable>
    | Release

let start count =
    let agent =
        MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
            let newToken () =
                { new IDisposable with
                    member x.Dispose () = inbox.Post Release }

            let rec loop n = async {
                    let! msg = inbox.Scan <| function
                        | GetToken _ when n = 0 -> None
                        | msg -> async.Return msg |> Some

                    return!
                        match msg with
                        | Release ->
                            loop (n + 1)
                        | GetToken port ->
                            port.Reply <| newToken ()
                            loop (n - 1)
                }
            loop count)

    { new IParallelLimiter with
        member x.GetToken () =
            agent.PostAndAsyncReply GetToken}

let limiter = start 100;;

for _ in 0..1000 do
    async {
        use! token = limiter.GetToken ()
        Console.WriteLine "Sleeping..."
        do! Async.Sleep 3000
        Console.WriteLine "Releasing..."
    } |> Async.Start
```