# HttpClient.Timeout does not seem to be working

Tags: .net, http, f#, dotnet-httpclient

The small test app tries to communicate with the server using HttpClient, with the Timeout specified.

But it looks like the timeout never aborts the client request:

```
#r "System.Core.dll"
#r "System.Net.dll"
#r "System.Net.Http.dll"
#r "System.Web.dll"
#r "System.Web.Http.dll"

open System
open System.Net
open System.Net.Http
open System.Threading
open System.Web
open System.Web.Http

let listener = new HttpListener()

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019466/httplistener-access-denied/4115328#4115328
// netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:7842/ user=COMPUTER\User
// netsh http show urlacl                   - make sure that it exists
// netsh http delete urlacl http://*:7842/ - delete it
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:7842/")
listener.Start()

let handler = async {
    while true do
        let context = listener.GetContext()
        Console.WriteLine("ok")
}

let requester = async {
    let client = new HttpClient()
    client.Timeout <- TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(float(1))
    client.BaseAddress <- Uri("http://127.0.0.1:7842/")
    try
        let! result = client.GetAsync("") |> Async.AwaitTask
        printf "result: %s" (string(result))
    with
    | _ -> printf "timeout?"
}

Async.Start(handler)
Thread.Sleep(750)
Async.Start(requester)

Thread.Sleep(100000)
```

The timeout never happen in this app which is very strange.

**Update:** It may be related to [HttpClient.GetAsync(...) never returns when using await/async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async)

**Update2:** It seems that this workaround is working but not sure if it correct:

```
try
    let requestTask = client.GetAsync("")
    let! success = Async.AwaitIAsyncResult(requestTask, 3000)
    let result = requestTask.Result

    printf "result: %s" (string(result))
with
| ex -> printf "timeout? %s\n" (ex.ToString())
```

Should the client be Disposed (probably not as it can be reused for another requests in other threads/tasks)?

Comment: Similar issue here, with likely a similar workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5713330/636019

Comment: @ildjarn Thank you - it looks like it will work.