# "Chaining" asynchronous functions in F#

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#

I have created a function in F# to recover historical data from Yahoo (the classic asynchronous example for F#):

```
let getCSV ticker dStart dEnd =
async   {
        let query = getFileUrl ticker dStart dEnd
        let req = WebRequest.Create(query)
        use! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse()
        use stream= resp.GetResponseStream()
        use reader = new StreamReader(stream)
        let content = reader.ReadToEnd()
        let ts = parseData content
        return ts
        }
```

Now, I can run this function asynchronously by doing the following:

```
let test=
    ["MSFT";"YHOO"]
    |>List.map (fun x -> getCSV x (DateTime.Parse("01.01.2000")) (DateTime.Parse("01.01.2010")))
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Ok that's cool.

Now, what I would like to know is how to apply some function to this which is the history of prices:

For example:

```
let getReturns (prices:(DateTime *float)list) =
    [for i in 1..(prices.Length-1) -> i]
    |> List.map (fun i ->(fst (List.nth prices i), (snd (List.nth prices i))/(snd (List.nth prices (i-1) )) - 1.0))
```

So the trivial way of doing it is:

```
let test2=
    ["MSFT";"YHOO"]
    |>List.map (fun x -> getCSV x (DateTime.Parse("01.01.2000")) (DateTime.Parse("01.01.2010")))
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> Array.map getReturns;;
```

However, the `getReturns` function is executed once every file is downloaded and parsed.

What I would like to know, is if it is possible to start execution the second function while the downloads are still taking place: once MSFT is done, no need to wait until YHOO is done to compute its return...

I know that I could modify `getCSV` but I would like to know if there is a way to "chain" the `getReturn` function without having to change a previously written module...

Comment: Related/similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693279/combining-f-async-functions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would typically write the call to the function directly inside an asynchronous workflow. This is mostly a matter of style or preference - I think that code written using asynchronous workflows is generally more explicit and doesn't use higher-order functions as often (though they're still sometimes useful):

```fsharp
let test=
    [ for stock in ["MSFT";"YHOO"] ->
        async { let! data = getCSV stock (DateTime(2000, 1, 1)) (DateTime(2010, 1, 1))
                return getReturns data } ]
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

This means that the workflows executed in parallel first get the data and then call `getRteurns` to extract the data. The entire operation is then parallelized.

Alternatively, you could either use Joel's solution (modify the `getReturns` function so that it takes an asynchronous workflow and returns an asynchronous workflow) or define a function `Async.map` that takes an asynchronous workflow and constructs a new one that applies some function to the result.

Using your original `getReturns` function, you can then write:

```fsharp
let test=
    ["MSFT";"YHOO"]
    // For every stock name, generate an asynchronous workflow
    |> List.map (fun x -> getCSV x (DateTime(2000, 1, 1)) (DateTime(2010, 1, 1)))
    // For every workflow, transform it into a workflow that 
    // applies 'getReturns' to the result of the original workflow
    |> List.map (Async.map getReturns)
    // Run them all in parallel
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

The definition of `Async.map` is quite simple:

```fsharp
module Async =
  let map f workflow = async {
    let! res = workflow
    return f res }
```

Comment: If I understand, I could also have written the `getCSV` writing it synchronously and the use exactly the same code you wrote to that it is processed asynchronously right?

Comment: The `req.AsyncGetResponse()` needs to be inside an async workflow, so you could only make `getCSV` non-async if you moved the WebRequest stuff out of that function.

Comment: I'm thinking it's because async.bind is just too similar.

Comment: Here's the [User Voice suggestion that includes Async.map](http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6367266-add-combinators-in-the-async-module). Go and vote if you want that feature.

Comment: how to include Async.map in the async module? It seem that it's still not included by default.

Comment: @stt106 You can just include the above snippet somewhere in your code and then open the module/namespace containing it.

Comment: And that's something called "extending" an existing module e.g. Async in F#? Or it doesn't have an official name.

Answer (score 4):

If you defined your `getReturns` function like this...

```
let getReturns (prices:Async<(DateTime * float) list>) = async {
    let! prices = prices
    return [for i in 1..(prices.Length-1) -> i]
           |> List.map (fun i ->(fst (List.nth prices i), (snd (List.nth prices i))/(snd (List.nth prices (i-1)))))
}
```

Then you would be able to do this:

```
let test=
    ["MSFT";"YHOO"]
    |> List.map (fun x -> getCSV x (DateTime(2000, 1, 1)) (DateTime(2010, 1, 1)))
    |> List.map getReturns
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

You could clean it up further by changing `getCSV` so that `ticker` is the last parameter instead of the first. This allows you to partially apply the date arguments to produce a function that only requires a ticker to execute. Then you can chain that function with `getReturns`.

```
let test =
    let getRange = getCSV (DateTime(2000, 1, 1)) (DateTime(2010, 1, 1))
    ["MSFT"; "YHOO"]
    |> List.map (getRange >> getReturns)
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

**Edit**:

All those `List.nth` calls in your `getReturns` function make me itchy. I'd rather use pattern-matching myself. I think you could write that function like this instead:

```
let getReturns2 (prices: Async<(DateTime * float) list>) = async {
    let! prices = prices
    let rec loop items output =
        match items with
        | (_, last) :: (time, current) :: rest ->
            loop rest ((time, (last / current)) :: output)
        | [ item ] ->
            List.rev (item :: output)
        | [] ->
            List.rev output
    return loop prices []
}
```

Comment: okay so basically if I don't have access to the `getReturns` function, I just create a wrapping function to accept the asynchronous input...

Comment: @SRKX - If you cannot modify `getReturns` then you could probably use `Async.map` (from my answer) quite easily. Essentially, it builds a wrapper (like the one you'd write by hand) for any function you give it.

Comment: @Joel: haha, I like your implementation of returns. mine was just an example ;)