# Is there a better way to cast a return value inside an async block in F#

Tags: f#

I'm using [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/) inside a small F# project and I need to cast the db.StringGetAsync() return value to an int. I've found a way to do it like this:

```
let! intFromRedis= async {
    let! value = db.StringGetAsync(key) |> Async.AwaitTask 
    return int value
}
```

But it would be prettier to be able to do something like this instead:

```
// Better syntax but it does not compile
let! intFromRedis : int = db.StringGetAsync(key) |> Async.AwaitTask
```

Is there a better syntax for this?

Comment: I can't try this where I am, but can't you just add `|> int` at the end?

Comment: @MarkPattison: The type 'Async<RedisValue>' does not support a conversion to the type 'int'

Comment: Perhaps you could use the `Async.map` Tomas Petricek describes here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6793961/126014

Comment: The Async.map example worked. Please answer the question so that I can approve it.

Comment: Why not just cast to int on a second line, or right where you use the value? It sounds like overkill to define and use `Async.map` just to maybe save one line of code.

Comment: @Vandroiy I'm new to F# and I'm learning. That is why I suspected that I might have overlooked some constructs. Keeping it DRY can be a good thing...

Comment: @Vandroiy it looks like your suggestion describes the original approach, that the OP wanted to improve upon.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @phoog Note that the code in the question is already a nested async. One could just cast in the outer workflow. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, technically, the question asks for `Async.map`, which could be defined similar to the code in the question.

But I'd rather recommend to keep it simple. Casting on a second line would look like this:

```
let! redisValue = db.StringGetAsync(key) |> Async.AwaitTask
let intFromRedis = int redisValue
```

And I'm not even sure `intFromRedis` is more readable than `int redisValue`. It's barely shorter, and the latter expression is self-explanatory. Thus, there's no real problem in keeping just the first line and using `int redisValue`.

Using rare or custom functions reduces readability. A cast – and maybe a value binding – are simple, short enough, and any programmer reading the code should understand what is happening.

Comment: I agree that `Async.map` is overkill.