# Optimizing syntax for mapped async sequences in F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#, sequence

I am trying to figure out efficient syntax for the following F# expression. Let's say I have an F# async computation:

```
let asyncComp n = async { return n }
```

It has a signature `'a -> Async<'a>`. Now I define a sequence of those:

```
let seqOfAsyncComps = 
    seq {
        yield asyncComp 1
        yield asyncComp 2
        yield asyncComp 3
    }
```

Now I have an item of `seq<Async<int>>`. What if I want to asynchronously map the elements from `seq<Async<int>>` to `seq<Async<int>>`. This won't work:

```
let seqOfAsyncSquares =
    seqOfAsyncComps |> Seq.map (fun x -> x * x) // ERROR!!!
```

Of course, `x` is `Async<int>`, I have to extract an `int` first, so I can do the following instead:

```
let seqOfAsyncSquares =
    seqOfAsyncComps |> Seq.map (fun x -> async { 
                                            let! y = x
                                            return y * y }) // OK
```

This works fine but the syntax is clumsy. It takes away F# compactness, and if I want to chain several `seq` processing I have to do the same trick in every `map`, `filter` or `iter`.

I suspect there might be a more efficient syntax to deal with sequences that consist of async computations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Async.map` (that I've only now blatantly [stolen from Tomas Petricek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6793961/126014)):

```
module Async =
  let map f workflow = async {
    let! res = workflow
    return f res }

let seqOfAsyncSquares' =
    seqOfAsyncComps |> Seq.map (Async.map (fun x -> x * x))
```

If you evaluate it, you'll see that it seems to produce the expected outcome:

```
> seqOfAsyncSquares' |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously;;
val it : int [] = [|1; 4; 9|]
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark, that's cool. Of course I can move the async plumbing into a separate function. BTW, the post that you referred to brings an interesting discussion with good examples. Just what I need now.

Comment: I'm constantly wondering why `Async.map` isn't built-in, but I just looked at [the source for F# 4, and it doesn't look like it's there](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/fsharp4/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/control.fs).

Comment: Here's the [User Voice suggestion that includes Async.map](http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6367266-add-combinators-in-the-async-module). Go and vote if you want that feature.

Comment: What about submitting a PR :)?