# Flattening nested async sequences in F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#, sequence

Consider a series of F# sequences:

```
let seqOf123 = seq { for i in 1..3 do yield i }
let seqOf456 = seq { for i in 4..6 do yield i }
let seqOf789 = seq { for i in 7..9 do yield i }
```

... and a sequence which contains all of them:

```
let seqOfSeqOfNums = 
    seq {
        yield seqOf123
        yield seqOf456
        yield seqOf789
    }
```

Now we have a sequence of sequences that we can flatten using built-in Seq.concat function and wrap in async clause to execute asynchronously:

```
let firstAsyncSeqOfNums = async { return Seq.concat seqOfSeqOfNums }
```

We have a resulting async sequence of 9 numbers with a signature `Async<seq<int>>`that we will come back to.

Now consider a series of async sequences:

```
let asyncSeqOf123 = async { return seqOf123 }
let asyncSeqOf456 = async { return seqOf456 }
let asyncSeqOf789 = async { return seqOf789 }
```

... and a sequence containing them:

```
let seqOfAsyncSeqOfNums = 
    seq {
        yield asyncSeqOf123
        yield asyncSeqOf456
        yield asyncSeqOf789
    }
```

We have now a sequence of type `seq<Async<seq<int>>>`. We can't flatten this one using Seq.concat because it's a sequence of async sequences. So how can we convert it to a type `Async<seq<int>>` where all integer data are flattened? We can try to do the following:

```
let secondAsyncSeqOfNums = 
    async {
        return seqOfAsyncSeqOfNums
        |> Seq.map (fun x -> x |> Async.RunSynchronously)
        |> Seq.concat
    }
```

It looks like it does its job: it has a type `Async<seq<int>>` and if we pipe it to Async.RunSynchronously it will produce the same sequence of 9 integers. But the way it produces the same sequence is not equivalent to firstAsyncSeqOfNums that appears above. The implementation of secondAsyncSeqOfNums calls Async.RunSynchronously for every nested sequence of integers during the generation of a singe flattened sequence. But can this be avoided? Note that we are generating an async flattened sequence that ideally would need only a single call to Async.RunSynchronously to evaluate its content. But I can't find a way to rewrite the code without Async.RunSynchronously being called multiple times.

Comment: it has a slightly different name but I think what you are looking for is [`Async.Parallel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353779.aspx) (you will probably want to use this together with some of the other functions you already mentioned - just play a bit ;) )

Comment: Async.Parallel turns a sequence to an array for parallel execution, but it can't be used to flatten sequence of a nested async sequences, can it?

Comment: It will basically get you `seq<Async<'a>>` into `Async<seq<'a>>` (so it pulls the `Async` out` - no you can continue with what you did with `Seq.concat` (or so I would) - IMO it's better than running everything synchronously as you lose every advantage from async)

Comment: btw: sadly (and somewhat strange) there is no `Async.map` so you cannot combine those really nice and have to dive into `async { ... }` or make `Async` into a functor yourself

Comment: Can you illustrate it with an example? I did play with Async.Parallel but couldn't get it to work for my purpose. And regarding Async.map, it's easy to write one as shown in the answer to my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459042/optimizing-syntax-for-mapped-async-sequences-in-f

Comment: BTW, Async.Parallel doesn't pull Async, it just turns seq into array, so I can't see how it can help in this case.

Comment: look at the type-signatures - it does pull Async out of seq! So if you have a map you can do something like `Async.Parallel wf |> Async.map Seq.concat` have a look at my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
> let aMap f wf = async {                              
-    let! a = wf
-    return f a
-    };;

val aMap : f:('a -> 'b) -> wf:Async<'a> -> Async<'b>

> let aConcat wf = Async.Parallel wf |> aMap Seq.concat;;   

val aConcat : wf:seq<Async<#seq<'b>>> -> Async<seq<'b>>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Yes, the combination of Async.Parallel and Async.map (aMap) did the trick.

Comment: glad I could help - that the nice thing in FP : get the types right and you are rather often good to go ;)

Comment: Yes I struggled for some time to get rid of multiple calls to Async.RunSynchronously. Now everything is perfect :-)