# When calling an F# async workflow, can I avoid defining a temporary label?

Tags: f#, async-workflow

Suppose I have an async data source:

```
let getData() = async { return [ 3.14; 2.72 ] }
```

I could call it using `let!` and a temporary label:

```
let showData1() = async {
    let! data = getData()
    data
    |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
}
```

Or, I could call it (inefficiently!) using `Async.RunSynchronously` and piping, and without a temporary label:

```
let showData2() = async {
    getData()
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
}
```

I like the syntax of `showData2` but know that calling `Async.RunSynchronously` ties up the calling thread.

Is there a syntax, operator, or function defined somewhere that allows me to pipe an `Async<'T>` into a function that accepts `'T`?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6793961/974789

Comment: I added a suggestion at http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/8151819-add-support-for-forward-piping-the-result-of-an-as

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want `map` for `Async`:

```
let mapAsync f a = async { 
    let! v = a
    return (f v)
}
```

then you can do:

```
let m: Async<unit> = getData() |> mapAsync (Seq.iter (printfn "%A"))
```

Comment: I marked this as the answer. It seemed perfect. However, now that I've been trying to use it for a couple days on my "real" project, I find that the syntax is still awkward. `mapAsync` returns an `Async<'T>`, unlike `Async.RunSynchronously`, which returns an 'T. I'm beginning to think that what I want will need to be a language feature like `let!` and `do!`, but for forward piping. Thoughts?